# Difference between "all" and "all the"

Tags: grammar

could anyone please tell me the difference between the two following sentencess? And which one is grammatical?

1- **All the children** in the world are different. And they love everyone unconditionally .

2- ***All children*** in the world are different. And they love everyone unconditionally .

Comment: Both are grammatical. There is no difference in meaning.

Comment: Are you only interested in the difference between *all the children* and *all children*, as the body of your question asks? Or are you interested in the difference between *all* and *all the*, as your question title asks?

Comment: @user1284969632635 Actually I know a little bit about the difference between "All" and "All the". I want to know the difference between "all the children" and "all children" in the given context.